# Connecting PowerBi report to mysql google cloud in order to have an automatic PowerBi service refresh

Tags: mysql, powerbi, mysql-connector

Connecting PowerBi report  to mysql google cloud in order to have an automatic PowerBi service refresh .
I' have tried to connect my msql database to an odbc driver and then connected to power bi it worked but  only when i m online i want a solution to refresh my report even when my pc is off
thank for helping me i really need a solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am even new to this. If you are using direct Query to get the data from the database it will be possible to refresh the Data even if the PC is off.

As far I know, in Power Bi desktop it doesn't support connect to ODBC data source using DirectQuery mode because for some data sources, an alternative approach is available: [connect directly to the data source using DirectQuery.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-use-directquery)

I could help you with the reference which might help you to set it up: [Enabling Direct Query for an ODBC based connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/odbc).